# Lists and Dynamic Updating

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is there a way I can make a list. I am trying to make a comment log which will include Name---Date---Comment. I will have 3 work books. Two workbooks will have two different lists of Name,Date and Comment then I want the third one to collect these lists into one master list based on the date. How would I go about programming the macro for that?
I understand the VBA Recorder. My problem is the size of the lists is undetermined. For example, there could be 5 comments in one book, and 3 comments in the second book. I'd like the the master list to have 8 comment logs in order based on date entered.

Comment: With regard to your edit I can only reiterate... get the recorder to generate the BASE code for you, THEN make it dynamic. As I said, if you're stuck on how to do that then you could ask for help but it would be better to at least make an attempt at starting the code. As per the FAQ, the existing source code should normally be provided. The fact that there isn't any is probably the reason that you got a downvote on this question. (Not from me, but I expected that it would happen.)

Comment: Currently I have dynamic ranges for Name Date and contents. Cant figure how to have the master list accept one date over another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the hey, I'm feeling bored anyway. I wrote this before you posted your latest comment, but if you have dynamic ranges you may be able to substitute the names of those ranges wherever I've used the CurrentRegion property for the source. See if you can follow this; it should point you in the right direction at least.

```
Sub CombineLists2()

    Dim rng_Source As Excel.Range
    Dim rng_Target As Excel.Range

    Dim wbk_1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wbk_2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wbk_3 As Excel.Workbook

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'I'd recommend doing a test here to ensure that
    'all three workbooks are open, which is one reason
    'that we're using object variables.
    'If one of the workbooks isn't open then it'll throw an error.
    'Obviously change the names to your own files.
    Set wbk_1 = Application.Workbooks("ATeam.xlsx")
    Set wbk_2 = Application.Workbooks("BTeam.xlsx")
    Set wbk_3 = Application.Workbooks("CTeam.xlsm")

    'You may want to delete any contents that are in the combined book first.
    wbk_3.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear

    'We'll now get a reference to the range containing the list.
    'You'll obviously have to change the references to suit where
    'your list is.
    'In this case we'll take the headings as well.
    'Note that CurrentRegion range will only work if there
    'is nothing directly adjacent to the list.
    wbk_1.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
     Destination:=wbk_3.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

    'That's the first workbook done.
    'The second one we may need to tweak a little because we
    'don't want the headings this time.
    'I'm going to use a range reference for this so that
    'it'll be a little more transparent than doing it in one go.

    'First we grab the whole list range including headings, just
    'as we did for the first list.
    Set rng_Source = wbk_2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    'Next, we offset that by 1 row and shrink the size of it by
    '1 row to get rid of the headings.
    Set rng_Source = rng_Source.Offset(1, 0) _
     .Resize(rng_Source.Rows.Count - 1, rng_Source.Columns.Count)

    'I'll use another range to get the location of the existing list
    'in the combined workbook.
    Set rng_Target = wbk_3.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    'Now we copy the second list and paste it to one cell below that range
    rng_Source.Copy Destination:=rng_Target.Offset(rng_Target.Rows.Count, 0)

ExitPoint:

On Error Resume Next

Set wbk_3 = Nothing
Set wbk_2 = Nothing
Set wbk_1 = Nothing
Set rng_Source = Nothing
Set rng_Target = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description

Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the StackOverflow spirit of encouraging problems to be attempted, I offer the following suggestion.

Are you familiar with the macro recorder? (It's on the Developer tab (which you may need to expose in your Excel ribbon options).)

If you record the action of doing this manually, the macro recorder will generate 90% of the code that you need.

The rest will involve you simply replacing the hard coded range references with dynamic references such as CurrentRegion to pick up the contents of the lists. If you get stuck in doing that, by all means post again.

I would recommend that you record the macro in the third (target) workbook so that it can simply suck the contents in from the source workbooks.